# How to know reactor is running or not in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, twisted, reactor, twisted.internet

How to know reactor status (running or not) ?

I tried this(searched from google):

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
if reactor.callWhenRunning(lambda: None) is not None: 
    # do some work
```

It worked, but this seems like weird way.

What can be other ways of doing this ?

Comment: The reactor is running if you have called `reactor.run`.  Why isn't this sufficient?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You do not state which reactor you are using, but [this page](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/13.1.0/api/twisted.internet.base.ReactorBase.html) says `ReactorBase` is the base class for Reactors.

Also on the same page, it mentions an instance variable `running` that is further explained [here](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/13.1.0/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorCore.html#running).

It says

> running = A bool which is True from *during startup* to *during shutdown*
>   and False the rest of the time.

With that information we can change your code to:

```
if reactor.running:
    # do some work
```

Comment: Nice find! :) It's not documented anywhere in it's PUblic API (*docstrings*).

Comment: @JamesMills are you sure? Check https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/13.1.0/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorCore.html#running ;-)

Comment: It doesn't seem to come up when you use ``pydoc`` :)